# Flask-Limiter does not work with Flask-Restful API-based application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, flask-jwt-extended

I am trying to build a RESTful API app with `flask_restful`, `flask_jwt_extended` for user authorization and `flask_limiter` to limit the quota of a user at 6/minute. My toy/testing code follows (no actual authorization schemes have been implemented yet):

```py
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, create_access_token, JWTManager, get_jwt_identity

# custom HTTP exception
class OutOfQuota(HTTPException):
    code = 402
    name = 'Out Of Quota'

app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(app, key_func=get_jwt_identity)

api = Api(prefix='')

class Token(Resource):
    def get(self, user):
        return make_response({'token': create_access_token(identity=user)})

class Test(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    @limiter.limit('6/minute')
    def get(self):
        return make_response({'message': f'OK {get_jwt_identity()}'})

api.add_resource(Token, '/token/<string:user>')
api.add_resource(Test, '/test')

api.init_app(app)

# custom error handler (change "Payment Required" to "Out Of Quota" HTTP status
@app.errorhandler(429)
def ratelimit_handler(e):
    return OutOfQuota(f'quota limit exceeded: {e.description}')

jwt = JWTManager(app)

app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'nothing-fancy-for-now'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

The endpoint `/token` generates a JWT token for the user, with their username stored inside as the JWT identity. When the `/test` endpoint is accessed with this token, I want to check how many times this specific user (i.e. this specific identity) has accessed this endpoint, hence the usage of `get_jwt_identity` as the `key_func` of the `Limiter`.

The problem is that I do not have any limit when I access the `/test` endpoint when I run the above code; I can access it as many times as I want, as fast as I want. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue and found a solution that seems to work. `Flask-Restful` does things a little differently. It creates pluggable views. There's a section in `Flask-Limiter` docs about this particular case - https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#using-flask-pluggable-views

```
class Test(Resource):

  decorators = [limiter.limit("5/minute")]

  def get(self):
     ...
```

Instead of providing the decorator via `@limiter.limit`, we need to provide it this way.

I also had an issue about where to get the reference of `limiter` from. In some base directory, you can implement this and import in your class.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

_app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(
    _app,
    key_func=get_remote_address
)
```

Comment: The link is now changed to - https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#rate-limiting-class-based-views