# Rate limiting a Flask REST API

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a simple REST API set up in my flask project, which I am trying to rate limit using the flask_limiter library.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, session, render_template
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# Api endpoint
class getData(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'data': 'data'}

api.add_resource(getData, "/data")
```

I tried adding the default `@limiter.limit()` decorator, but it doesn't seem to work. When I tested it, only the default limits were working.

```
limiter = Limiter(
    app,
    key_func=get_remote_address,
    default_limits=["1000 per day", "3 per hour"]
)

class getData(Resource):
    @limiter.limit("1 per minute")
    def get(self):
        return {'data': 'data'}
```

Instead of limiting the access to 1 per minute, as specified in the decorator, it used default limiter values instead.

**Is it possible to rate limit my API using this method and how can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you solved your problem already but here is what will work in your situation. Need to include it in the method_decorators field that flask restful provides. More information can be found in the following links.

[Flask limiter Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369112/flask-limiter-does-not-work-with-flask-restful-api-based-application)

[Flask restful method decorator](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#resource-method-decorators)