# Flask Rate Limiter not working with flask-restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, rate-limiting, flask-limiter

I believe I have the same problem as described here: [Flask-Limiter does not work with Flask-Restful API-based application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369112/flask-limiter-does-not-work-with-flask-restful-api-based-application). But I still can't get it to work. Here's my problem:

- I have an `app.py` where I import all my REST-API endpoints. I use flask-RESTful resources as described in this guide: https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html
- I use the "Flask-Limiter" library for rate limiting: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. The rate-limiter gets instantiated in a separate file, not inside `app.py` because this would create circular references between `app.py` and the REST-API endpoints. I think this could be the cause of my problem.

This is the rate-limiter file (located in: `/controller/helpers/rate_limiter.py`)

```py
from flask import current_app
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

limiter = Limiter(
    current_app,
    key_func=get_remote_address
)
```

This is the `app.py` file (located in: `/`):

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from controller.actions.my_endpoint import MyEndpoint

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(flask_app)
api.add_resource(MyEndpoint, '/endpoint')
flask_app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

And finally this is an example of an endpoint (located in: `/controller/actions/my_endpoint`):

```py
from flask_restful import reqparse, Resource
from controller.helpers.rate_limiter import limiter


class MyEndpoint(Resource):
    decorators = [limiter.limit("1/minute", methods=["POST"])]
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.parser.add_argument(
            "someData", type=int, nullable=False, required=True)

    def post(self):
        data = self.parser.parse_args(strict=True)
        someData = data.someData

        return "Got your message {0}".format(someData), 200
```

I would expect that after the first request I would get response 429 because the rate limit of 1/minute is reached but it doesn't do that.

However, when I instantiate the limiter inside `app.py` and set a default rate-limit, it works (getting that error 429):

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from controller.db_actions.my_endpoint import MyEndpoint
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

flask_app = Flask(__name__)

limiter = Limiter(
    flask_app,
    key_func=get_remote_address,
    default_limits=["1 per minute"]
)

api = Api(flask_app)
api.add_resource(MyEndpoint, '/endpoint')
flask_app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**Question:** I think I'm doing something wrong with instantiating the limiter. What is it? :)

Comment: Interesting... I'm seeing the same issue here.  I guess you never figured it out?  I have it working if I instantiate it in __init__.py where I declare my app but if I try to instantiate it with current_app in a blueprint file it doesn't seem to work.  Curious.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by using a utils.py file and importing limiter from that.

In utils.py

```py
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

# Setup the Rate Limiter
limiter = Limiter(
    get_remote_address,
    default_limits=["100 per hour", "10 per minute"],
    storage_uri="memory://",
)
```

Then I imported it and used the `init_app()` method on the limiter to make it work as expected.

In the `__init__.py`

```
from .utils import limiter

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="static", static_url_path="/static")

limiter.init_app(app)
```

Now I can import it into my blueprint and it works:

```
from rest_api.utils import limiter

@employee_blueprint.route("/")
@limiter.limit("1 per second")
def get_employees(session=""):
   ... code here ...
```

I was inspired by [this article](https://www.codementor.io/@pietrograndinetti/build-a-production-ready-api-with-rate-limiter-in-15-minutes-1f2kfdlp9b).